# Exit code of 1 from SSH command

Tags: ssh, grep, tty

Why would the following return a 1:

```
ssh -tt server_name "sudo grep 'something' /path/to/file || [ $? = 1 ]"
```

The command in double quotes when run directly on server_name returns 0. Why is the ssh command considered to have failed?

I have the key for the user set up on the remote server. So if I login as userA on serverA, I can simply do the following:

```
ssh -tt server_name
```

and login as userA on server_name. So, I know that is not the issue. Is it the -tt? The double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$?` in double quotes is expanded locally before `ssh` even starts. The remote server most probably gets

```
… || [ 0 = 1 ]
```

and because of this an exit status `1` is possible.

Exchange quotes to pass the literal `$?` string to the server. It will be expanded on the remote side:

```
ssh -tt server_name 'sudo grep "something" /path/to/file || [ $? = 1 ]'
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much for schooling me on that! I literally just thought of removing the quotes before I saw this and it worked. So inverting the quotes prevents expansion of the $?? Is the fact that $? gets expanded in some documentation? I can't find it in the ssh man page.

Comment: @KingTouchstone It's the shell that expands `$?`, not `ssh`.

Comment: @KingTouchstone The most general documentation is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_02). This is what any POSIX compliant shell should obey.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have found the GNU documentation for bash where this is specified, 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes. It seems that using double quotes with grep -P does not affect the regex based on what I understand in that documentation.